# Namespaced Join Table Refers to Itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  has_many :memberships, :class_name => "User::Group"
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :members
  has_many :members, :class_name => "User::Group"
end

class User::Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I make the following association call:

```
@user.groups
```

And it returns an array of `User::Group`s, instead. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the join table to `User::Membership`, and now everything works as expected. It seems that naming the last part of the namespace after another model was causing some sort of interference, though I'm not sure why. Does anyone have a more informed explanation?